# force application to reconnect after xx ms in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing an iPhone application which is completely based on web data.
If there is a connection outage the application shows network error message

If there any idea to put in place an implicit re-try connection solution 1 time re-try only 
Solution details :
When an outage 
Let the application sleep 500 ms then after re-try to connect 
If outage is persist  display the network error message
Else user will get connected without the message

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look to [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). You may handle the connection lost event (calling, i.e, the `streamError` method of `NSStream`), then create and schedule a `NSTimer` setting `NO` in `repeats` field of the initializer. The timer will call the fire method after the time you set (this case you may try to reconnect in the function call) only once.

Comment: Why do you need it? you can write here

Comment: As I mentioned before the iPhone application is completely based on web data 
So the network error problem can comes from different levels 

Level 1-[no internet connection on the iPhone ] If your IPhone is switched to airplane mode  you will get the exception “ network error or network temporary is not available “
Level 2-[web data is not responding ] if the web data is not responding 

For me I need to identify the level1 exception and apply the retry solution 
How I can differentiate between the level 1 and the level 2 ? 

Many thanks for your answer

Comment: This is really a different question - search for Reachability